# Return False not working inside jQuery.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

**P.S.: Read "EDITED on 2019-06-29":**

I have a webform for updating user information, and when he updates his email a verification is performed via `ajax()` so that he is warned if the new email address is already in use by another user.

I'm trying to cancel the form submission when the email is in use, but `return false;` doesn't work.

Any other `return false;` within if statements are working fine, the problem is only with this one inside the `jQuery.ajax()` call.

Here's the actual code:

```
var email = jQuery('#email').val();
jQuery.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : '/ajax/verify-email.php?email=' + email,
    success : function( d ) {
        if( d == '1' ) {
            alert('Another user is using this email');
            jQuery('input[name="email"]').focus();
            return false; // this guy over here is not working!!!!
        }
    }
});
```

Does anyone have a solution?

**EDITED on 2019-06-29**

When I asked this question back in 2012 I wasn't aware of Promises in Javascript, neither knew about "$.when" (even though added 3 years later of this question) to handle asynchronous requests alongside $.ajax.

Today, you can handle the same scenario easily, as this:

```
let email = $('#email').val();
$.when(
  $.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : `/ajax/verify-email.php?email=${email}` 
  })
 .then(function(d) {
   alert('Another user is using this email');
   $('input[name="email"]').focus();
});
// your code continues from here as desired...
```

Comment: why do you need it to return false?  Is this part of a larger code block that could help somebody answer the question?

Comment: what do would you expect it to do there? Probably it should be somewhere else to block a form submission

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The A in AJAX is actually very important. It stands for Asynchronous. This means that you trigger a request to the server which might take some time to process and you get a response later. This response happens inside the success callback. But since this happens much later than the actual form submission, your form has actually been already submitted before the response comes back. So returning false from an AJAX success callback makes no sense whatsoever. What you want to do is to return false from the submit handler of your form. Let's see how we could implement this.

You could subscribe to the `.submit` handler of the form and send an AJAX request to verify whether the email has already been taken or not and if it is not taken manually trigger the submission of the form inside the success AJAX callback:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    // we send an AJAX request to validate the unicity of the email
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/verify-email.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { email: $('#email').val() },
        // we set the context to the form so that inside
        // the success callback 'this' points to the form
        context: this,
        success: function(result) {
            if (result != '1') {
                // If the server send something different than 1
                // we know that the email is unique and trigger
                // the submission of the form using the underlying
                // DOM element to avoid calling the .submit handler
                // recusrively
                this.submit();
            } else {
                // The email is not unique => we are informing
                // the user that the email is already in use
                alert('Another user is using this email');
                $('#email').focus();
            } 
        }
    });

    // we cancel the normal submission of the form    
    return false;
});
```

Also never rely on client side validation. Make sure that you are performing the `email is unique` check once the form has been successfully submitted to the server. If you are using a SQL database that's easily achieved with a unique constraint on your Email field.

Comment: You can avoid the `proceed` flag entirely if you call the submit function of the form directly; calling `HTMLFormElement#submit` doesn't trigger submit handlers. But note that there's a race condition here; the user could change the email *while* the ajax call is running, resulting in sending in the changed (and unchecked) email. (BTW, you use `proceed` in one place, `process` in the other.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, good tip about using the actual DOM element to submit the form. Will update my answer. Also thanks for noticing the `proceed` vs `process` data attribute. As far as the race condition is concerned, well, that's why one should absolutely never rely on client side validation and make sure to enforce this validation on the server.

Comment: Other than the completely unjustified use of "unicity". ;-) Just giving you a hard time, it was always okay. Now it's even better. One nit I might pick is that `$(this).get(0).submit();` is an *awfully* long way to write `this.submit();` ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, OMG: `$(this).get(0).submit();` -> that is a good candidate for thedailywtf.com :-) As far as `unicity` is concerned, well, Google Chrome underlines, so I know it is wrong but I just dunno the correct word.

Comment: `@Darin`: LOL! It's actually a word: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unicity Most people would have said "uniqueness." Here I thought you were showing off your vocabulary. (Great answer, btw, upvoted long ago.)

Comment: Yep, the problem was with the assynchronous request.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `.submit()` on this situation, use a flag system instead, `.submit()` should only be used for `<form>` elements.

```
var email = jQuery('#email').val();
var flag = 0;
jQuery.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : '/ajax/verify-email.php?email=' + email,
    async: false,
    success : function( d ) {
        if( d == '1' ) {
            alert('Another user is using this email');
            jQuery('input[name="email"]').focus();
            flag = 1;
        }
    }
});
if(flag == 1) return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You run async code here. At the moment you are trying to return false, it is far to late. Your function already returned `undefined`. You need to provide a callback if you want to process the result of your success.

Answer (score 0):

you should use event.preventDefault() as shown below.

```
$('#form').submit(function(event) {
    $.get('/ajax/verify-email.php?email=' + $('#email').val(), function(d) {
        if (d == '1') {
            alert('Another user is using this email');
            $('#email').focus();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="yourpage" method="post" onsubmit="return matchpass();">
  <div>
   <label> Name</label>
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  </div>
  <div>
   <label> Email ID</label>
   <input type="email" name="email" id="email">            
  </div>
  <div>
   <label> Mobile No</label>
   <input type="text" name="mob"  maxlength="10" onkeyup="check_if_exists();" autocomplete="off" id="mob">
  </div>                             
  <div>
   <button type="button" >Send</button>
  </div>
  <span id="err"></span>
  <div>
   <label> OTP</label>
   <input type="password" name="otp" id="otp"  maxlength="6" placeholder="****">
   <span id="err2"></span>
  </div>    
  <div>
   <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="reset-btn">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" >              
  </div>
</form>
<input type="hidden"  id="otpcheck"/>



<script>
function matchpass()
{

     $.ajax({   
    type:"post",
    url: "yourpage",
    data:{ mobile:mob,otp:otp},
    success:function(data)
    {
       if(data==1)
       {
           document.getElementById("otpcheck").value=1; //important
       }else{

           document.getElementById("err2").style.color = "red";
           document.getElementById("err2").innerHTML = "invalid OTP Number ";
         document.getElementById("otpcheck").value=0; //important
       }


    }
    });

    if(document.getElementById("otpcheck").value==0){
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').submit(function() {
// we send an AJAX request to validate the unicity of the email
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/verify-email.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { email: $('#email').val() },
    // we set the context to the form so that inside
    // the success callback 'this' points to the form
    context: this,
    success: function(result) {
        if (result != '1') {
            // If the server send something different than 1
            // we know that the email is unique and trigger
            // the submission of the form using the underlying
            // DOM element to avoid calling the .submit handler
            // recusrively
            this.submit();
        } else {
            // The email is not unique => we are informing
            // the user that the email is already in use
            alert('Another user is using this email');
            $('#email').focus();
        } 
    }
});

// we cancel the normal submission of the form    
return false;
```

});

Comment: This is literally just the code from the answer, but you ruined the formatting.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you don't realy get the idea jQuery. You don't need to use return false, and not there. You can call `event.preventDefault();`:

```
$('#form').submit(function(event) {
    $.get('/ajax/verify-email.php?email=' + $('#email').val(), function(d) {
        if (d == '1') {
            alert('Another user is using this email');
            $('#email').focus();
        }
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/9wNNk/).

Comment: that's not the problem. He tries to return a value in an async function^^

Comment: I tried async false in jquery ajax, but it didn't work as well4