# MVC: pass parameter to action using Jquery.ajax()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, parameter-passing

I'm pretty new to `MVC`. I need to make `ajax` call to an `Action` with parameters using `html.Action()`. I'm unable to pass this..

Hope it will be helpful for other MVC begineers as well..

**HTML:**

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Add Race", "AddRace", 
        new {eventId = Model.EventId, fleetId=Model.SelectedFleet.ID}, 
        new{@onclick=string.Format("return checkFleetAddedandScroing()")}) %>
```

**Jquery:**

```
 function checkFleetAddedandScroing() {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '<%=Url.Action("CheckFleetExists")%>',
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                data = eval("(" + data + ")");
                if (data == true) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    alert("Cannot Add race becasue you have not yet added any fleets and fleet scoring is checked.");
                    return false;
                }
            }, //success
            error: function (req) {

            }
        });           
    }
```

**Action:**

```
  public JsonResult CheckFleetExists(Guid fleetId )
    {
        bool exists = false;
        try
        {
            exists = !db.Races.Any(r => r.FleetID == fleetId);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return Json(exists, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I need to pass `fleetid` to action which is in `Model.SelectedFleet.ID`. Its being used somewhere on pages. But i'm unable to use that somehow..

please suggest where i'm doing wrong...

Comment: have you checked whether your action is hitting?

Comment: no..its not being hit...Instead it shows alert message which is written in else part of success..

Comment: It's not being hit because the action `CheckFleetExists` will always return false, and your JavaScript function will always return false as well. Where or how are you passing a GUID to `CheckFleetExists`?

Comment: i think you have two mistakes, one suggested by agarhy.and the second is @ sign before onclick.

Comment: And, by the way, there is a reason why the `Json` method does not, by default, allow for GET requests. It's to prevent hijacking. Consider making a POST request for JSON data instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to invoke a controller action using AJAX when the link is clicked and depending on the result of this call either allow the user to be redirected to the actual `AddRace` action or be prompted with an error message.

The problem with your code is that you are attempting to return true/false from within the success AJAX callback which doesn't make any sense. You need to always return false from the click callback and inside the success callback, depending on the returned value from the server, redirect manually using the `window.location.href` function.

**HTML:**

```
<%: Html.ActionLink(
    "Add Race", 
    "AddRace", 
    new {
        eventId = Model.EventId, 
        fleetId = Model.SelectedFleet.ID
    }, 
    new {
        data_fleetid = Model.SelectedFleet.ID,
        @class = "addRace"
    }
) %>
```

**Jquery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.addRace').click(function (evt) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '<%= Url.Action("CheckFleetExists") %>',
                cache: false,
                data: { fleetId: $(this).data('fleetid') },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.exists) {
                        // the controller action returned true => we can redirect
                        // to the original url:
                        window.location.href = url;
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Cannot Add race becasue you have not yet added any fleets and fleet scoring is checked.");
                    }
                },
                error: function (req) {

                }
            });

            // we make sure to cancel the default action of the link
            // because we will be sending an AJAX call
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Action:**

```
public ActionResult CheckFleetExists(Guid fleetId)
{
    bool exists = false;
    try
    {
        exists = !db.Races.Any(r => r.FleetID == fleetId);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    return Json(new { exists = exists }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Remark: inside your `AddRace` controller action don't forget to perform the same verification as you are doing inside your `CheckFleetExists`. The user could simply disable javascript and the AJAX call will never be done.

Comment: this one was also unable to hit break point placed on action..Thanks for your support Darin..+1 for you..i solved it by my own efforts..

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly. In your example you are still returning true/false from within the success callback which is wrong. You are not returning false from within the `checkFleetAddedandScroing` function itself and so you are not canceling the default action.

Comment: ohh that's why it always returns false..and shows message box every time..and redirect regardless of `return false` statement..is that right Darin..?

Comment: It always redirects because you never return false from your click handler which is not right.

Comment: Sorry Darin, for not accepting your answer earlier. :D well thanks a ton for make me more clear about `$.ajax()`..i was bit confused about it..but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422215/return-false-not-working-inside-jquery-ajax of your worked great for me..you are the real `MVC` man on SO..thanks a lot.. :)

Answer (score 1):

change your action like this :

```
 public JsonResult CheckFleetExists(string fleetId)
    {
        var fleetGuid = Guid.Parse(fleetId);
        bool exists = false;
        try
        {
            exists = !db.Races.Any(r => r.FleetID == fleetGuid );
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return new JsonResult{ Data = exists};
    }
```

and change you ActionLink so :

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Add Race", "AddRace", 
    new {eventId = Model.EventId, fleetId=Model.SelectedFleet.ID}, 
    new{onclick=string.Format("return checkFleetAddedandScroing({0})",Model.SelectedFleet.ID)}) %>
```

and your script block may look something like this :

```
function checkFleetAddedandScroing($fleetId) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<%=Url.Action("CheckFleetExists")%>',
            dataType: "json",
            data : { "fleetId" : $fleetId },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                data = eval("(" + data + ")");
                if (data == true) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    alert("Cannot Add race becasue you have not yet added any fleets and fleet scoring is checked.");
                    return false;
                }
            }, //success
            error: function (req) {

            }
        });           
    }
```

Comment: I think he might have a problem with the `checkFleetAddedandScroing` JavaScript function as well. I don't think he is passing any data to the action in the AJAX request. I am too lazy to correct it right now though. Would you mind doing the honors? :)

Comment: it didn't work even it was unable to hit breakpoint placed on action..but somehow i solved it..However it improved me a lot..+1 for you..

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in answers that url to action was not complete..i did it using this way

```
function checkFleetAddedandScroing() {
       // debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<%=Url.Action("CheckFleetExists", new {eventId=Model.EventId})%>',
            dataType: "json",                
            cache: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                data = eval("(" + data + ")");
                if (data == true) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    alert("Cannot Add race becasue you have not yet added any fleets and fleet scoring is checked.");
                    return false;
                }
            }, //success
            error: function (req) {

            }
        });
    }
```